# How to dynamically change which column to filter?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create copies of entire workbooks (as there are other sheets, formatting, etc. I want to preserve) and then delete out rows of data that do not equal the current cl.value. The column headers will always be in row 1.  The worksheet can have a varying amount of columns (i.e. A:D, A:F, A:G, etc.) and the end user can select any column to split by.

Referencing a cell works but if try to make it dynamic (based on user selection mentioned above) in the following part of the code:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=FName
            'Delete Rows
            'REFERENCING ACTUAL CELL WORKS
            'Range("A1").AutoFilter 1, "<>" & cl.Value
            'BELOW DOES NOT WORK
            Range(ColHead).AutoFilter 1, "<>" & cl.Value
```

I get a

> Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object'_Global' Failed

Full Code Below:

```
Sub DisplayUserFormSplitWb()
UserFormSplitWb.Show
End Sub

Private Sub BtnOK_Click()
Call SplitWbMaster.SplitWbToFiles
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim SplitOptions As Range
Set SplitOptions = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlToRight))
SplitWbCol.List = Application.Transpose(SplitOptions.Value)
End Sub

Sub SplitWbToFiles()
   Dim cl As Range
   Dim OrigWs As Worksheet
   Dim Subtitle As String
   Dim ColValue As String
   Dim ColStr As String
   Dim ColNum As Long

   Set OrigWs = ActiveSheet

   ColValue = UserFormSplitWb.SplitWbCol.Value

   Set ColHead = Rows(1).Find(What:=ColValue, LookAt:=xlWhole)
   Set OffCol = ColHead.Offset(1, 0)
   ColStr = Split(ColHead.Address, "$")(1)
   ColNum = ColHead.Column
   If OrigWs.FilterMode Then OrigWs.ShowAllData
   With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
      For Each cl In OrigWs.Range(OffCol, OrigWs.Range(ColStr & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
         If Not .exists(cl.Value) Then
            .Add cl.Value, Nothing
            'Turn off screen and alerts
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            'Create workbook copy
            FPath = "U:\"
            Subtitle = UserFormSplitWb.SplitWbSubtitle.Value
            FName = FPath & cl.Value & "_" & Subtitle & ".xlsx"
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=FName
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=FName
            'Delete Rows
            'REFERENCING ACTUAL CELL WORKS
            'Range("A1").AutoFilter 1, "<>" & cl.Value
            'BELOW DOES NOT WORK
            Range(ColHead).AutoFilter 1, "<>" & cl.Value

            ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Delete

             Range(ColHead).AutoFilter
             Range(ColHead).AutoFilter
            'Rename sheet
            ActiveSheet.Name = Left(cl.Value, 31)
            'Refresh save and close
            ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
            ActiveWorkbook.Save
            ActiveWorkbook.Close False
         End If
      Next cl
   End With
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   MsgBox "Splitting is complete. Please check your Computer (U:) drive.", vbOKOnly, "Run Macro"
End Sub
```

Comment: You should say EXACTLY which line of code causes the error. One possibility is that you are deleting a range (c1) and then referencing it after it's been deleted.

Comment: Change Range (ColHead).Autofilter  to ColHead.Autofilter...

Comment: @barneyos I changed that and now all the tables in my split out files are blank... could it be because ColHead was set in my OrigWs and new workbooks don't understand that reference?

Comment: @TonyM my bad - there is a comment in my full code but I should have made it more apparent in the question part. I edited my post.

Comment: Do You want to set Autofilter in just opened workbook ? If Yes, then code should be:  Range(ColHead.Address).AutoFilter 1, "<>" & cl.Value and in next lines too. If You work with more than 1 workbooks, better is to create Set referenece for each wbk. Try smtg like Set newWbk = Workbooks.Open Filename:=FName and call next e.g. newWbk.Sheets(1).Range("A1"). Thats' better to control active environment

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who might stumble upon this question -

I have found that using the below code solves my issue:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).AutoFilter ColNum, "<>" & cl.Value
```

where:

```
Dim ColNum As Long
ColNum = ColHead.Column
```